# SmsManager SendDataMessage in Android

Tags: android, sms

I was using the Android SmsManager provided API [sendDataMessage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendDataMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20short,%20byte[],%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) to send SMS messages and noticed that the behavior seems to change from different devices, Here are my observations.

I am able to send messages successfully

1. On all devices (Nexus 6p, Nexus6, Nexus5) if Cellular data is turned on
2. **On Nexus6p** only if cellular data is turned off

**My Questions:**

1. Are there any internal changes that occured? Is this device specific/ carrier specific or API specific?
2. How is the sendDataMessage different from the sendTextMessage with respect to the communication channel used?
3. Does the byte[] data sent to the API needed to be 7 bit encoded?

Comment: Check the sim card SMS balance...

Answer (score 1):

Regular (text) SMS messages are sent over the cellular network control channel.  You can read a good description of exactly what's going one here: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/e-mail-messaging/sms.htm

When you use `sendDataMessage`, you're sending over your cell data channel.  This is separate from the voice and control channels.  That's why nothing gets sent when cell data is off.

The encoding depends on the language and whether it's text vs. data.  See 'Message size' in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service

SMS is complex.  You might want to look at a solution provider like Twilio instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: I don't think you're right.  sendDataMessage just uses port based SMS, which IIRC is still sent over the SMS channel and doesn't require a data connection.  Its been a while, but I used that back in the mid-2000s for a few apps and they went through even with no data connection.

Comment: @GabeSechan in looking at this further, it seems both may be correct.  Several sources confirm data sms messages are sent over cell data channels.  Others show that data is sometimes sent over the same channels as text, but with protocol additions.  The Android base source has at least some references to this second technique.  A few of the references I found: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9108/what-is-a-data-sms http://www.gsm-modem.de/sms-pdu-mode.html http://www.androidauthority.com/what-is-sms-280988/